# How to translate webxr camera to orientation in scene

Tags: three.js, webxr

I've been working on a 3D viewer application, and got into a little trouble with webxr and threejs scene rendering.

I have a simple sphereGeometry around the camera that has a cubemap image stretched over it, to create a 3D viewing experience. After switching to WebXR mode, I'd like a plane to follow the user's rotation, basically to stay in view all the time. This would be the initial state of the menu, and the user can minimize/maximize it later if needed, via gaze tracking.

My issue is, that I have a hard time making sure the plane stays in sight at all times.

I'm using the XRSession's requestAnimationFrame to update everything according to the camera movement, based on an online tutorial. The scene is completely viewable, so I'm guessing the transformations based on the tutorial work well.

In the render cycle I tried updating the plane's position based on the camera's worldDirection like so:

```
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
var position = new THREE.Vector3();

camera.getWorldDirection(direction);
camera.getWorldPosition(position);

plane.position.copy(position.clone().add(direction.multiplyScalar(3)));
plane.lookAt(position);
```

Unfortunately this only causes the plane to move ever so slightly, and not in a way that it stays in view all the time.

Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original problem to the situation in question was not with the transformation of the plane, but how the scene was moved when the camera was rotated. So the above code works, but I made a mistake of applying the camera's matrixWorldInverse to the whole scene, which included the plane as well. Transforming it into a place where it should not have been. Without that, the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to add your plane as a child of the camera. That is generally the easiest way to make sure an object is transformed with the camera, as it happens automatically due to how object hierarchy works.

```
camera.add(plane);
scene.add(camera);
```

Comment: This works in a way that the plane is always in view for sure. Unfortunately with this solution the user is unable to interact with the plane by looking at it.

Comment: @ferenc.d I see. So you want the plane to somehow follow the camera but not be in exactly the same reference frame? Could you then specify how you want the plane to be transformed with respect to the camera?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I'll also update the question with this info. It would be a floating menu-like component that is always half-visible(some of it off-screen, to not take up too much of the FOV), and its position is updated based on the rotation and view direction of the camera, with a delay. The delay would be there, in case the user looks directly at it, not just around the space, we can bring it out to full view.

Comment: The way I handle this is to have both the camera and the menu be children of a "rig".  The rig represents your "body" position, camera can move independent in the rig and plane can be positioned wherever you want relative to the camera (exactly where depends on if you're using 6DOF or not).  I also often use "object3D.lookAt(cam.position)" to make sure the menu is facing the camera.